# Merge not working for insert a record when it's doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I use `Merge` to insert a record when it's doesn't exist like below,

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].[Test] AS [Target]
USING (SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [dbo].[Test]) AS [Source]
    ON [Target].[Name] = [Source].[Name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Id], [Name])
VALUES (NEWID(), 'Hello');
```

If the record with value `Hello` does not exists in table `Test`, insert it otherwise don't do anything. With above code record is not inserted even I don't have this record in table. And there are no errors.

I know how to accomplish this using `insert ... where not exists (...)` but am specifically wanting to know how to do it using a merge statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your merge statement wasn't working is that you were merging the same table, `dbo.Test`, back onto itself, so of course there is no missing record.

You can insert a single missing record as follows, where you create a *source* query to contain the record(s) you wish to insert:

```
declare @Test table (id uniqueidentifier, [Name] nvarchar(64))

select * from @Test

-- Returns
-- id                                   |   Name
-- ----------------------------------------------

MERGE INTO @Test AS [Target]
USING (select 'Hello' [Name]) AS [Source]
ON [Target].[Name] = [Source].[Name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Id], [Name])
VALUES (NEWID(), [Name]);

select * from @Test

-- Returns
-- id                                   |   Name
-- ----------------------------------------------
-- C1C87CD5-F745-436D-BD8D-55B2AF431BED |   Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer from Dale K. Its correct.

If I suppose you might have a source_table from where the data needs to get inserted and not to get inserted if the record already exists then you can do the following.

Instead of the MERGE you can

```
insert
  into dbo.Test
       (id
        ,name
        ) 
  select top 1 
         newID()
        ,'Hello'
   from dbo.Test a
  where not exists(select 1 
                     from dbo.Test b 
                    where b.name='Hello')
```